# after upgrade perl from 5.16.3 to 5.28.1 facing issue in time locale output

Tags: perl, datetime, locale

After upgrading perl from 5.16.3 to 5.28.1.  DefaultLocale function of DateTime.pm is giving different output compare to 5.16.3

locale command gives the following output

```
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Local;
use Params::Validate qw(:all);
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use POSIX qw(setlocale LC_TIME);

my $locale = setlocale(LC_TIME);
DateTime->DefaultLocale($locale);
print "Time locale :",DateTime::DefaultLocale;
```

perl 5.28.1 gives output

```
Time locale :DateTime::Locale::FromData=HASH(xxxxxx)
```

whereas perl 5.16.3 output was

```
Time locale :DateTime::Locale::de_DE=HASH(xxxxx)
```

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem? Also, which versions of DateTime are you comparing?

Comment: Tip: `DateTime::DefaultLocale` is supposed to be `DateTime->DefaultLocale`, though that won't have an effect on the output you get

Comment: The difference you are seeing is the result of differences in the internal structure of the two versions of the DateTime-Locale package you are using. As an internal matter, it shouldn't have any consequence to you unless you are doing something you shouldn't. I'm guessing the change happened in DateTime-Local-1.00

Comment: Perhaps there is a relevant (i.e. non-internal) difference that's relevant to you, but seeing as you didn't mention it, ask a question or specify a problem, we can't help you with that.

Comment: The problem is we have test suite that was running with perl 5.16.3 and now after perl upgrade, one of the test case is failing with the difference in time locale output as shown above. old version and new version of Datetime is 1.19 and 1.51 respectively. Also my problem is here how "FromData" is comming in place of de_DE in the test output. I have compared the "DefaultLocale" and its internal subroutine "load" of both DateTime versions, i could not figure out any difference there, any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by printing out an internal object reference instead of something meaningful and portable?

Comment: Actually this is print statement inside subroutine(which Initialise the time locale for process) which called by the script so script is doing many other actives as well.

Comment: Sounds like your test suite is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be testing for the class name. Perhaps you should be testing the code returned by `DateTime->DefaultLocale->code`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime qw( );

DateTime->DefaultLocale('de_DE.utf8');

my $locale = DateTime->DefaultLocale;
say ref($locale);
say $locale->code;
say $locale->day_stand_alone_wide->[0];
```

Output:

```
DateTime::Locale::FromData
de-DE
Montag
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, updated the test case as suggested to verify the  DateTime->DefaultLocale->code